# Ищу хорошую литературу по языку R

Tags: книги, r

Кто-нибудь занимается программированием на статистическом языке R? Хотелось бы найти литературу **на русском языке**, более продвинутую, чем начальные понятия. Я использовала материалы

1. Е.М.Балдин, А.Б.Шипунов, С.В.Петров, А.И.Коробейников (и др). *Анализ данных с R.* Части I, II, III.
2. Д.Мертц, Б.Хантинг. Статистическое программирование на R. (Три части).

и некоторые разрозненные материалы. Также есть желание задать вопросы по конкретным задачам и методам.

Comment: Я отстал от жизни - первый раз слышу :)

Comment: Например, [здесь][1]


  [1]: http://www.wowebook.me/tag/r/

Comment: Извините, не добавила "на русском языке". А то я бы просто их "родные" сайты читала.

Comment: Нет, просто "оно вам не надо". Это свободно распространяемый аналог статистического языка S. Мне нужно его преподавать, а заодно и использовать в обработке данных.

Comment: Очень плохо. Если не можете читать литературу на анлийском, это очень плохо.

Comment: "преподавать R" - пожалейте студентов

Comment: Почему, я могу читать на английском. Просто времени больше займет. Да и рекомендовать студентам труднее.

Comment: А что плохого для студентов?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну например вот - [Наглядная статистика. Используем R!](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7952180/) - самый свежак. Если живёте в москве то достать не проблема. Если не в Москве то придётся подождать доставку)

Comment: Вот это спасибо!